# create regex to match format of 00:00:00 for duration (not time)

Tags: php, regex, laravel, duration

Hi i'm using laravel and I want to validate create a regex which will allow a specific format for duration (not time as this can exceed a 24 hr format). so for example 124hrs 30 mins and 24 secs would be represented as follows 124:30:24. But the first value can be over 1 character and a number, the second value needs be a colon, the third value needs to be 2 characters and a number, the fourth value needs to be a colon and the fifth value needs to be 2 characters and a numbers.

Any ideas how I can create an regex that will achieve this to insert into the following array?

```
$rules = array(
  'duration'          => 'required|regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/'
);
```

invalid examples:

```
alphacharacters e.g. qwerty
0:0:0
0:
0
1
30:211:211
30:2111:2111
a:d:d
asd
```

valid examples:

```
01:00:00
1:00:00
30:21:21
330:21:21
1330:21:21
11330:21:21
basically any amount of hours.
```

Comment: could you add some example that are valid and not valid please?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro have done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give your examples this regex should suffice:

```
^\d+:\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kO4xN2/2

`\d` is a number
`+` is a quantifier meaning one or more of the preceding character (or group)
`{}` is an amount of characters to allow (you can give it a range as well)
`^$` are anchors, so the string must be an exact match, if there is more content in the string this should be removed.